# How to run a service dependency only on boot?

Tags: systemd, services

I have a long-running systemd service, let's call it `db.service`. It is enabled to start on system boot, but can also be restarted manually.

I also have a `oneshot` service, les's call it `check.service`, that performs an integrity check on the database file.

`check.service` should be run on system boot, and during boot `db.service` should not start if `check.service` fails.

But! Here's the caveat: `check.service` should NOT be run when `db.service` is restated manually using `systemctl restart db.service`. And it should be possible to start `db.service`  manually even if `check.service` fails on boot.

#### Question

Is there a way to achieve this using systemd services?

#### Thoughts and observations

- I though I could achieve this by using `RequiredBy=db.service` in `check.service`. But that still triggers `check.service` when `db.service` is started.
- Maybe the problem can be solved in some way by creating a third service, `db-boot.service`, that has dependencies on boot `db.service` and `check.service`. But I haven't been able to figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `check.service` to be of `Type=oneshot` with `RemainAfterExit=yes`, and it needs also be `WantedBy=db.service` and ordered `Before=db.service`

Then at boot time (or before the first startup of the database, if the database is not configured to start at boot time), the `check.service` runs to completion and is left in `active (exited)` state. So when `db.service` is restarted, `check.service` is already active and satisfies the dependency, so `check.service` won't restart.

With this setup, if `check.service` fails on boot, `db.service` will not be started (but since using a `Want` dependency instead of `Require`, the rest of the system will start up normally instead of dropping into emergency mode). If `db.service` is then started manually, it will require `check.service` to run once successfully first. After `check.service` is run successfully, then `db.service` can be started and stopped at will.

---

If `db.service` needs to be able to be started manually when `check.service` is failing, then you might instead want to configure `db.service` to not start automatically at all (i.e. `systemctl disable db.service`), and remove the `WantedBy=db.service` from `check.service`. Instead, you would have `check.service` explicitly run `sudo systemctl start db.service` *if and only if* the check is successful.

This way, there will be no dependencies requiring `check.service` to run when starting `db.service` manually, but `check.service` will auto-start the database only if the check is successful (presumably at boot time).

Comment: Thanks telco. I will evaluate this. I am currently messing with a solution that uses a third service, `db-boot.service`, that has `Requires=check.service` and `OnSuccess=db.service`. I am optimistic about this, but haven't gotten it to work yet.

Comment: Thanks telecoM, I ended up using a variation of solution. I use a separate `db-boot.service` that depends `check.service`. In `db-boot.service` I use `ExecStart=systemctl start db.service`. In that way I can also run `check.service` manually, without starting `db.service` as a result.